# Xamarin.Andorid не могу подключиться к коллекции Kinvey

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

Есть некая коллекция на бекэнде, называется "cars". Ниже скрин[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот описание сущности:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Kinvey;

namespace DaysTaxi.Droid
{
    [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class Car : Entity
    {
        public Car() { }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("photo_id")]
        public string PhotoID { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("class_id")]
        public int Class { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("_kmd")]
        public KinveyMetaData Meta { get; set; }


        [JsonProperty("_acl")]
        public KinveyMetaData acl { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("_id")]
        public int id { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Я пытаюсь подключиться к этой коллекции из кода следующей строкой, используя API:

```
 DataStore<Car> cars = DataStore<Car>.Collection("cars", DataStoreType.SYNC);
```

Возникает исключение **object reference not set to an instance of an object**.

При этом, остальной функционал с бекэндом работает: работа с пользователями, сессиями, файлами.

В итоге: проблема в том, что **не могу подключиться к коллекции из кода проекта**.

Буду рад помощи.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Что вы имеете вв виду - "возвращает null и соответствующее исключение"? Так не бывает, или возврат или исключение.

Comment: object reference not set to an instance of an object - исключение

Comment: Правильно исключение, но не возврат же. Поправте.

Comment: Исправил, спасибо.